# Parse error on input

Tags: haskell

Why does this Haskell code produce `Parse error on input '='` at row 9 (`t = 1`)?

```
module Main where
import System.IO
import Data.List.Split
main = do {
    flag <- isEOF;
    if flag then return 0
    else do {
        s <- getLine;
        t = 1;
        print s;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because it is a `do`-block and you need `let`.

Comment: If I add let at the beginning of that row I get "parse error in let binding: missing required 'in'" instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a `let` for the declaration of `t`, and you should use some indentation instead of braces and semicolons:

```
module Main where

import System.IO
import Data.List.Split

main = do
  flag <- isEOF
  if flag
    then return 0
    else do
      s <- getLine
      let t = 1
      print s
```

Comment: Most Haskell code uses indentation, but braces and semicolons are legitimate.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson legit, yes, but imo they should be omitted where they are not necessary when you use multiple lines. I see them only in one-liners.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, you have missed a `let` keyword before `t = 1`. I was surprised to see that you still get a parse error once this is added.

A syntactically valid solution with braces and semicolons as in your original example is:

```
module Main where
import System.IO
import Data.List.Split
main = do {
    flag <- isEOF;
    if flag then return 0
    else do { s <- getLine
            ; let t = 1
            ; print s
            }
}
```

In order to get it to compile you can change `return 0` to `return ()`:

```
module Main where
import System.IO
import Data.List.Split
main = do {
    flag <- isEOF;
    if flag then return ()
    else do { s <- getLine
            ; let t = 1
            ; print s
            }
}
```